# How to keep prompting the user when they enter nothing

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I have a simple `do while` loop here. The only problem I am having is this loop right now is only accepting numbers. I need it to accept everything except a blank input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean notValid = true;
        int numberAsInt = 0;
        do {
            try {
               System.out.print("Enter a number to Convert > ");
               String number = scan.nextLine();
               numberAsInt = Integer.parseInt(number);
               notValid = false;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }

        } while (notValid);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused on what you asked because you are parsing the result in your code, but I hope this is what you are asking of:

```
public class Assignment6 {
public static void main(String[]args){
   Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
   boolean notValid = true;
   String  input;
   do{
           System.out.print( "Enter a number to Convert > "  );
           input = scan.nextLine( );
           if(!input.isEmpty())
             notValid = false;

    } while ( notValid );

   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much this was the most helpful

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please accept it as the response then.

Comment: Hey one more thing. I am working with bases, and I need to make an error message. Can i just post my code in here?

Comment: It would be better to post a new question but be sure to search the site for any response that might help with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
String number = readLine("Enter a number to Convert > ");
while(number.isEmpty()){
     number = readLine("Please enter a *non-blank* number > ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we are comparing if entered value is space than not valid will be true

```
 try {
                   System.out.print( "Enter a number to Convert > "  );
                   String number = scan.nextLine( );
                   if(number.equals(" "))
                   {
                     notValid = ture;
                     sysytem.out.println(" Please do not enter blank space");
                    }
                    else
                   {
                     numberAsInt = Integer.parseInt(number);
                     notValid = false;
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet in your code:

```
if(number.trim().equals(""))
                       {
                         notValid = ture;
                         sysytem.out.println(" Please do not enter blank space");
                        }
```